# How to compare the filecontent difference between two remote files using Shell?

Tags: curl, sh, diff

How does one compare the filecontent difference between two remote files with a single line Shell command, without using Bash?

An attempt could be running a file `attempt.sh` with content:

```
#! /bin/sh
diff $(curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dockerfile/ubuntu/master/README.md") $(curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dockerfile/ubuntu/master/Dockerfile")
```

Note, as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash), the  `<()` process substitution from bash is not available in shell.

Comment: Use [`rsync` in `--dry-run` (`-n`) mode`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57305/rsync-compare-directories).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diff` operates on files, not on content passed in parameter. Command substitution (`$(...)`) replaces the command with its content, this is not the tool you need.

What you actually need is what is called process substitution (`<(...)`), which replaces the command with a pseudo-file (actually a pipe) that contains (actually conveys) the result of the command, which is executed in a sub-process.

```
diff <(curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dockerfile/ubuntu/master/README.md") \
     <(curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dockerfile/ubuntu/master/Dockerfile")
```

Unfortunately, as you added in note, this is a `bash` extension that is not known to POSIX shells (`/bin/sh`). To my knowledge, there is no solution with `/bin/sh` and you have to save at least one of the two `curl` outputs in a file:

```
$ tmp=$(mktemp)
$ curl -o "$tmp" "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dockerfile/ubuntu/master/README.md"
$ curl "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dockerfile/ubuntu/master/Dockerfile" \
  | diff "$tmp" -
$ rm -f "$tmp"
```